# Create a orthogonal lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, create, perpendicular

I have a shapefile of lines and I would like to know an Arcmap tool to create a new shapefile  with orthogonal lines from the midpoint of that existing line shapes. I know that it is possible to do it manually, but I have so many lines so it would be an impossible way.

Does anybody know an automate way to do it?

---

[image: example]

Yes, perpendicular lines that cross the middlepoint of the existing lines. An example would be like this:

Comment: You want perpendicular lines? Could you add a screenshot of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workflow based on this article: [How To: Create evenly spaced lines perpendicular to a line feature](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012318). It will work with a Basic license and can be automated with ModelBuilder or arcpy. Your data must be in a projected coordinate system.

1. Create routes from your input lines with the [Create Routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/create-routes.htm) tool (see step 1 in the article).
2. Create points in the middle of the line, either with [Feature to Point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-point.htm) if you have an Advanced license, or:

   - add the XY coordinates of the line's centroid to the attribute table with [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) (check the `CENTROID_INSIDE` property)
   - turn the XY coordinates into a point feature class with [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) and [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm).
3. Create an event table to locate those centroids along the routes with [Locate Features Along Routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/locate-features-along-routes.htm). Make sure you set the line ID field as Route Identifier Field parameter.
4. Add 2 'offset' fields (numeric) to the event table. They will define the start and end vertices of your perpendicular line (populate them with e.g. 10 and -10 if you want a 20 m long line, with equal length segments on each side of the main line).
5. Run [Make Route Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/make-route-event-layer.htm) twice with your event table as input. Make sure you set the line ID field as Route Identifier Field parameter. Use your first offset field as offset parameter the first time, and the second offset field the second time.
6. [Merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) the 2 point layers you've just created into one and create lines with [Points To Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm). Again, make sure you set the line ID as Line Field parameter. There you are!

If you want to have perpendicular lines on only one side of the original line, create only one offset point layer and merge it with the centroids layer. Make sur you map the line IDs to the same field in the output.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'l try this way and the others explained in the other links.